# Update problem with update_option() in combination with register_setting()

Tags: plugin-development, theme-options, settings-api, options

**Intro**

I have a settings page which includes a setting with a more complicated callback function to save.

**Save data**

To save the data I use the `register_setting()` function with a custom sanitize callback. I implemented it exactly as the WordPress settings API explains so this works fine.

**Remove data from option**

To remove data from this option array I use jQuery in combination with an AJAX callback function.

**The problem**

The problem is that I cannot use `update_option()` (in my AJAX callback) when the `register_setting()` is also active. I know this because when I comment out the `register_setting()` function, the `update_option()` suddenly works well, where it with the register_setting() uncommented deletes the option.

Does anyone have experience with this problem and knows what I can do to use both functions to update the option?

**Setup and register setting**

```
function gtp_init_theme_options() { 

    $page = 'services-settings-page';

    /**
     * Services settings sections and fields
     */
    $section = 'installing_settings_section';

    // Add installation settings section
    add_settings_section( $section, _x( 'Installing', 'Measure and installing', 'gtp_translate' ), 'gtp_display_installing_settings_section', $page );

    // Add and register installation areas
    $id = 'installing_data';
    add_settings_field( $id, __( 'Installing data', 'gtp_translate' ), 'gtp_settings_installing_data_fields', $page, $section, array( 'id' => $id, 'label_for' => $id ) );
    register_setting( 'services-theme-settings', $id, 'gtp_register_installing_data_setting' ); 

}
add_action( 'admin_init', 'gtp_init_theme_options' );
```

**The sanitize callback called by the register_setting()**

```
/**
 * Sanatizes callback for saving installation areas
 */
function gtp_register_installing_data_setting() {

    // Initialize object
    $installing     = new Installing();

    $error = false;

    // Check if country isset
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['existing_country'] ) ) {
        $country = strtolower( $_POST['existing_country'] );
    } elseif ( ! empty( $_POST['country'] ) ) {
        $country = strtolower( $_POST['country'] );
    } else {
        $error = true;  
    }

    // Check if zipcode isset
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['existing_zipcode_area'] ) ) {
        $range = $_POST['existing_zipcode_area'];
    } elseif ( ! empty( $_POST['zipcode_from'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['zipcode_to'] ) ) {
        $range = $_POST['zipcode_from'] . '-' . $_POST['zipcode_to'];
    } else {
        $error = true;  
    }

    // Check if product isset
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['existing_product'] ) ) {
        $product = strtolower( $_POST['existing_product'] );    
    } elseif ( ! empty( $_POST['product'] ) ) {
        $product = strtolower( $_POST['product'] );
    } else {
        $error = true;  
    }

    // Check if price isset
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['price'] ) ) {
        $price = str_replace( ',', '.', $_POST['price'] );
    } else {
        $error = true;  
    }

    // No errors
    if ( ! $error ) {

        // Add row to data array
        $installing->addRow( $country, $range, $product, $price );

        // Return data array
        return $installing->getData();

    }

}
```

**AJAX callback function**

```
/**
 * Remove installing data in admin AJAX handle
 */
function gtp_remove_installing_data() {

    // Initialize object
    $installing     = new Installing();

    // Remove product
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['country'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['zipcode_area'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['product'] ) ) {
        $installing->removeRow( $_POST['country'], $_POST['zipcode_area'], $_POST['product'] );
    } 
    // Remove zipcode area
    elseif ( ! empty( $_POST['country'] ) && ! empty( $_POST['zipcode_area'] ) ) {
        $installing->removeRow( $_POST['country'], $_POST['zipcode_area'] );
    }
    // Remove country
    elseif ( ! empty( $_POST['country'] ) ) {
        $installing->removeRow( $_POST['country'] );
    }

    // Update 
    $installing->update();

    die;        
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_remove_installing_data', 'gtp_remove_installing_data' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_remove_installing_data', 'gtp_remove_installing_data' );
```

I have attached an image of the settings screen for your imagination what kind of project I am working on.

[image]

Comment: Well it will be better if you share your code?

Comment: @Sumit I have added the code now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note what happens when you provide sanitize callback in `register_setting()`. It register a filter to sanitize your options

```
add_filter( "sanitize_option_{$option_name}", $sanitize_callback );
```

Now when you do `update_option()` then trigger your own function to prevent saving :D

Because `update_option()` calls `$value = sanitize_option( $option, $value );`

**Solution:**
Remove `register_settings()` callback before you call `update_option()`.

```
function gtp_remove_installing_data() {

    //Your code 

    //Remove sanitizing for adding
    remove_filter( "sanitize_option_installing_data", 'gtp_register_installing_data_setting' );

    // Update 
    $installing->update();

    die;        
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a hunch, but it seems to me that this problem has something to do with the order in which the operations are called.

If you have defined your hooks `wp_ajax_remove_installing_data` and `wp_ajax_nopriv_remove_installing_data` in your plugin and hooked that plugin in the usual way into WP with the `init` hook, it means this code is executed before `register_setting`, which you hook into `admin_init`, which is [later in the queue](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference).

Now, you are updating the option directly, not through the Options API. As you can read at the bottom of the [codex page on `update_option`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option), this means the cache is not updated. So, you are deleting the option, but when `register_setting` is called further on, it gets the value from the cache and sets it again.

The solution would be to [clear the cache](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_cache_delete) after updating the option, or to hook `register_setting` in `init` as well and make sure it has a higher priority than your update function, so the latter is executed after the call to `register_setting`. Disclaimer: I haven't tried this.

Comment: _it means this code is executed before register_setting, which you hook into admin_init_. Completely wrong! every Ajax callback is called after `admin_init` is done. Take a look [here](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.5/src/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php#L44)